# I want to make my div to full screen when page load in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am working with the javascript to display my div to full screen . i have a function which call on button click and my screen turns into full screen mode but i want the full screen on page load.

**what i have tried is**

```js
function togglescreen(){
    var element = document.getElementById("video-container");
    element.requestFullscreen();
}
```

```html
<button id="fullscreenBtn" onclick="togglescreen()">Full Screen</button>
<div id="video-container" width="1000" height="500"></div>
```

it works perfectly but i need full screen into my page load. i also tried

```
document.getelementbyId("fullscreenBtn").click();
```

but it's also not working.

Comment: Have you looked for `window.onload`?

Comment: yes window.onload is not working as well

Comment: @fazalabbas requestFullscreen  function not exists, can you provide?

Comment: Please share reproducible code.

Comment: it is built in function of javascript for full screen window

Comment: i have added all the code for the toggle full screen .

Comment: _it works perfectly_ How? I don't see it working in the code provided.

Comment: without this built-in code, we can't make nothing.

Comment: It's built into the browser @naxsi you can review it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, it needs to be triggered by the device or user input.  It'd be easily abused otherwise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen

> Note: This method must be called while responding to a user
> interaction or a device orientation change; otherwise it will fail.